# How to add additional keyboard layouts in Manjaro XFCE?

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, manjaro

Is there a straight way to use multiple keyboard layouts in Manjaro XFCE?
I've seen answers for KDE. Also I've seen tricks with setxkbmap. Is there a normal straight way to switch layouts with a key combination?

[UPD]: In the UI only English US and German layouts are available. The English one is active. The German is disabled. How can I add more to switch between them with a hotkey? I don't even need an indication. I can cope with typing a couple letters to see what layout is active now.

Comment: Try *Applications > Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout*, then **unclick** Use system defaults, and then you can add more layouts.

Comment: Please clarify your question to indicate if you are trying to find the key combination to switch layouts or support them at all.